# why do I get an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0 "

Tags: java, backtracking

I have to backtracking with numbers in a list that represent restrictions, such as: "x1 + x2> = 1". And if it meets all the conditions, that array is added to another array, in addition there is another list that represents the sum that I must make with all the variables "x1 + x2 + x3 + x4" and with that search for the one with the minimum value.

good what I should do in backtraking is to make a binary matrix with all the possibilities that the restrictions meet. What I have done is this but I get the error: "Exception in thread" main "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 0" and I don't know where my problem is.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Pra_hacer_pruebas {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Pra_hacer_pruebas a = new Pra_hacer_pruebas();
           ArrayList<Integer> conf1= new ArrayList<>(); // conf1 is the list that will contain one of the possibilities that may or may not be added to the binary matrix.
           ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>pos_v = new ArrayList<>();// pos_v is where the possibilities will be added, binary matrix
           int[][] restric = new int[2][2];// restric is the list with restrictions
           restric[0][0]=2;
           restric[0][1]=1;
           restric[1][0]=4;
           restric[1][1]=2;
           for(int t=0;t<4;t++){
               conf1.set(t, -1);
           }
           //System.out.println(conf.get(i));
           a.binario(conf1,restric,0,0,0,pos_v,0,4,-1);
    }

    public void binario(ArrayList<Integer> conf1, int[][] restric, int suma,int filas,int columnas,ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> pos_validas,int posicion, int cont,int bin){
        //filas = rows, suma= sum is to see if it meets the condition, columnas = columns, pos_validas = pos_v, posicion is to advance the rows of the matrix, cont: is the amount of different variables, bin is the binary variable
        Boolean booleano = false;  // booleano is the flag that if it is true it is because there was a null position (-1)
        for (int[] restric1 : restric) {
            suma=0;
            for (int co = 0; co < restric1.length; co++) {
                if ((conf1.get(restric1[co]) == 1) || (conf1.get(restric1[co]) == 0)) {
                    suma = suma + conf1.get(restric1[co]);
                } else {
                    booleano = true;
                }
            }
            if (booleano == false) {
                if (suma < 1){
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (booleano == false) {
            pos_validas.set(posicion, conf1);
            posicion++;
        }
        for (int f = 0; f < cont; f++) {
            if (conf1.get(f) < 1) {
                bin++;
                conf1.set(f, bin);
binario(conf1,restric,suma,filas,columnas,pos_validas,posicion,cont,bin);
            }
            bin--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what the exception means?

Answer (score 0):

Try `add` method. Even if you create ArrayList with initialCapacity, It won't works as you intended. If you print ArrayList size before `set`, You can check it.

```
System.out.println(conf1.size());
for(int t=0; t<4; t++){
    conf1.set(t, Integer.valueOf(-1));
}
```

Modify code to use `add`

```
for(int t=0; t<4; t++){
    conf1.add(-1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your Arraylist objects start out as empty objects. YOu can't call `.set()` on them at all: Those UPDATE existing entries, they don't make new ones. Try `add`.

Comment: I made the changes but I get almost the same error only in another index
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4"